# Regular expression for accepting only alphabets and within 2 to 5 char length

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

Accept:

- `text`
- `Text`

Don't accept:

- `text1`
- `text@`
- `123@#`
- `Te12$`

Comment: have you tried to write a regex to solve this? what does it look like? where is your code?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
const isValid = str => /^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/.test(str);
console.log(isValid('test')); // true
console.log(isValid('Test')); // true
console.log(isValid('test1')); // false
console.log(isValid('text@')); // false
console.log(isValid('123@#')); // false
console.log(isValid('Te12$')); // false
```

Comment: No its not working . for example, this is my input  "text@".It returns true only

Comment: @Tamil.S What do you mean?

Comment: I want my input string allow only alphabets and accept 2 to 5 char length.

Comment: @Tamil.S `/^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/.test('text@')` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: var regExp = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/;      userInput="text%":                 if(userInput.test(regExp))  alert('yes').  else alert('no')

Comment: @Tamil.S Try `var regExp = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/; var userInput = 'text%'; if (regExp.test(userInput)) alert('yes'); else alert('no');`.

Comment: I try this one also...not working. returns true only

Comment: @Tamil.S Please show your whole code.

Comment: Sorry,I tried this logic in online editor.